# Adding a new html page in django app

Tags: html, django

Newer to django... and I'm trying to new html page in my django app and it doesn't seem to be rendering. I'm receiving a 404 error.

[Output of 404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGqAE.png)

I've successfully added other pages using this method, but for some reason it's not working anymore.

Steps I took:

1. Added new html file to **dashboards/templates** folder
2. Added new class to **views.py**
3. Imported new class into **urls.py** and added to **urlpatterns**

Troubleshooting:

1. I've restarted Apache

---

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.generic import View
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
#from Minerva.backend.backend import CustomLDAPAuthBackend
from django.contrib.auth.backends import RemoteUserBackend

import logging

#logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


## Main Dashboard page
class DashboardsView(View):

    def get(self, request):      
        return render(request, "Dashboards.html")

## Documentation
class DocumentationView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, "Documentation.html")
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from Dashboards.views import DashboardsView
from Dashboards.views import AmbulatoryQualityView, CancerCenterView, DecisionSupportView
from Dashboards.views import EnterpriseQualityView, HumanResourcesView, IPAnalyticsView, ManagedCareView, DocumentationView
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

app_name = 'Dashboards'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', DashboardsView.as_view(), name='Dashboards'),
    url(r'^/Ambulatory Quality$', AmbulatoryQualityView.as_view()),
    url(r'^/Cancer Center Service Line$', CancerCenterView.as_view()),
    url(r'^/Decision Support$', DecisionSupportView.as_view()),
    url(r'^/Enterprise Quality$', EnterpriseQualityView.as_view()),
    url(r'^/Human Resources$', HumanResourcesView.as_view()),
    url(r'^/IP_Analytics$', IPAnalyticsView.as_view()),
    url(r'^/Managed Care$', ManagedCareView.as_view()),
    url(r'^/Documentation$', DocumentationView.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: Change `/Documentation$` to `/Documentation/$`

Comment: Post your root urls.py as well, some of your base confs aren't correct. Patterns #23 and 5 are the same, for example.

Comment: @SancaKembang - Adding the forward slash at the end of Documentation ended up fixing the issue. Thank you! I'm wondering why this would fix the issue for the Documentation page, but the previous 7 pages in the urlpatterns load perfectly fine. Is this best practice to include the forward slashes before and after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Apache it's all in your urlpatterns, firstly for `r^/Documentations$` should be `r^Documentation/$`, do not use capital letters in your URL, do not use spaces when you want long url so `r'^/Cancer Center Service Line$'` will be `r'^cancer-center-service-line/$'` and so on for the rest.